# Grid - button click handler

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc, extjs4.1

In my `Grid`, when I click on the Action button (the delete and edit button shown in the code below), I need to pop open a window without alerting the user with a Alert message;

In the following code I am using a HANDLER `handler: buttonClicked` and trying to access the row value i clicked from a different function below

```
buttonClicked :function (){...}
```

1. I don't know how to do this, can someone please help me ?
2. Can i access the row I clicked and display its name from the `Controller` class ?

---

**CODE SNIPET**

```
Ext.define('CountryAppTest.view.user.Gridview', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.store = 'store';
        this.columns = [{
            xtype: 'ac',
            items: [{
                icon: 'lib/extjs/examples/restful/images/delete.png',
                handler: buttonClicked
            }]
        }, {
            text: "username",
            dataIndex: 'username'
        }];
        this.viewConfig = {
            forceFit: true
        };
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    buttonClicked: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
        Ext.Msg.alert("Info", "name " + rec.get('username'));
    }
});
```

Comment: The answer to both your question is yes. Have you had a look a the [MCV docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture)? You should be able to work out how to do this from there.

Comment: I have tried the MVC doc, but i still couldn't get this working.

Comment: you have wrong bracket on line 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the parameters `(grid, rowIndex, colIndex)` into your `buttonClicked` declaration.

Comment: When i do that it says `handler: buttonClicked is not defined`.

Comment: in the declaration where you have buttonClicked: function() {}

Comment: change to `handler: this.buttonClicked`

Comment: What if i want to have the buttonClicked function in the Controller class, how can i pass the arguments and execute the function in the Controller class ?

Comment: Then you need to subscribe to these events from inside the controller class

Comment: Yeah, how will the controller know that this particular button was clicked, and how do i pass the arguments from the View class to the Controller class ? any clue ?

Comment: You really need to read and walk through http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/application_architecture